# Can't create a table with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When I execute my code I have this error:

[image: Error]

```
CREATE TABLE tblContactUs 
(
  contactUsID uniqueidentifier primary key default (newid()),
  name varchar(30) not null,
  newsletter VARCHAR(1) constraint check newsletter check(gender in ('Y','N')) default('N'),
  dbo.UseLogin foreign key references dbo.UseLogin(userID)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the database from `master` to ProjectjeSQL

Comment: @user1404946 In the drop down list box at the top left. Or add a `USE ProjectjeSQL;` statement at the beginning of the script.